# Error: token "@" is not valid in preprocessor expressions

Tags: mysql, c, linux, compiler-errors

Can anyone tell me what would be the cause of the error

`/mysql_com.h:306:5: error: token @ is not valid in preprocessor expressions`

while this mysql_com.h file does not contain any  **@**.  So how can I fix this error.

I think it's similar to the error when we open windows edited file in linux, then at that time **^V appers**. But in this case **@** is not anywhere in the file.

Thanks in advance. Looking for your kind response.

Comment: I would use a utility to check for invisible characters (something like `od`). `@` is sometimes a NULL character...

Comment: Go to line 306 in `mysql_com.h`. What does it say?

Comment: line 306 is as follows : IF MYSQL_VERSION_ID >= 200000

Comment: @Floris can you help me how can i use the od tool in centos.

Comment: Has the file been somehow converted to unicode?

Comment: @paddy I didn't get you ? I have open the file only in vim editor. How the file gets converted to unicode

Comment: It was a question.  I didn't say you had done it.  You know, programming is all about considering possible scenarios and testing.  I am merely putting a possibility out there, given the present lack of information surrounding your problem.

Comment: I didn't you. Please explain what you are saying

Comment: Sometimes, `@` appear in files not yet transformed by `autoconf` .... Did you run `configure` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this sort of problem has been reported when a '.h.in' file is included at some point, instead of the usual '.h' header file (eg. [this](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?462378-GNU-compile-error-quot-token-is-not-valid-in-preprocessor-expressions-quot))  - perhaps because of some missing files or misconfigured include paths?
As has been previously suggested, I'd try tracing things back through the definition of `MYSQL_VERSION_ID` and double check that the correct .h files and include paths are present on your machine.

Comment: thanks everybody for giving me your precious time. I have solved this problem by editing the file mysql_version.h. In this file i have replaced @MYSQL_VERSION@ with the current version.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check what is stored in  **MYSQL_VERSION_ID**. Go to the library file, where this constant defined having the syntax like below :-

**#define MYSQL_VERSION_ID        BLAH-BLAH**

Try to resolve this **BLAH-BLAH**, because this definitely have some problem, that have "**@**" symbol.